# How to extract information stored in llvm.ident?

Tags: clang, llvm

I want to extract following string

```
"clang version 10.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git aa71c977ba9828496270f53edd66665c8244f679)"
```

from

```
!llvm.ident = !{!6}
!6 = !{!"clang version 10.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git aa71c977ba9828496270f53edd66665c8244f679)"}
```

I tried

```
NamedMDNode *NM2 = M.getNamedMetadata("llvm.ident");
NM2->dump()
```

but not sure how to get the information in string format.

Comment: I suspect, `Module::getNamedMetadata("llvm.ident")`

Comment: I did that but it will not extract the information in string format .. I need the information in string format as I want to then process that string

Comment: I guess, you have to iterate over `NM2`s operands until you can `ConstantDataArray` or something like that.